# How to create multiple object that have same content in ArrayList without manually input?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

This is my sample code, in my Users List, there have 10 Users inside and half of them have same value. I wan to ask how can I do so that this half of duplicate object can be generate without manually input?

```
--User Class--

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class User {
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private int age;



public User(String firstName,String lastName, int age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}


    /**
 * @return the firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
/**
 * @param firstName the firstName to set
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
/**
 * @return the lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
/**
 * @param lastName the lastName to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
/**
 * @return the age
 */
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
/**
 * @param age the age to set
 */
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}


}
```

This is main class.

```
--Main Class--

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<User> users= new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
    users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
    users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
    users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
    users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
    users.add(new User("David", "So", 20));
    users.add(new User("Rowan", "Yeo", 21));
    users.add(new User("Joshua", "Low", 23));
    users.add(new User("Jackson", "Lim", 21));
    users.add(new User("Daniel", "Fo", 21));

     users.forEach(user -> {
            System.out.println(user.getFirstName() + "," + user.getLastName());
     });
}
```

How can I do so that I allow to generate 1/2 duplicate user of All users in the list without manually input?

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: Use for loop...
`int arrsize = users.size();
for(int i=0;i<arrsize;i++) {
 users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
}`

Comment: @ScaryWombat it poorly works with mutable classes.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a for loop like this?

```
List<User> users= new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    users.add(new User("James", "Lim", 24));
}
```

Or you can use a method like this to add users when you have many duplicates,

```
private static void addUsers(List<User> users, int count, User user) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        users.add(user);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    addUsers(users, 5, new User("David", "So", 20));
}
```

Comment: as per @talex comment above, your second method doesn't work well with mutable classes